# Как правильно запомнить, на что ссылается this?

Tags: javascript

Смотрю видео-урок по стрелочным функциям. И там автор привёл пример:

```
let person = {
    name: "Bob",
    greet: function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name);
            console.log('this is', this);
        }, 2000);
    }
};
```

Но, как человек, работающий с javascript уже какое-то время, я знаю, что `this` в теле `setTimeout` ссылается на `setTimeout` и в этом примере эта проблема решается при помощи стрелочной функции, но почему тогда this в этом случае ссылается на объект person, а не на `greet: function()`? И как наиболее эффективно запомнить, когда и на что ссылается `this`?

Comment: Лучше почитайте об этом тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods

Answer (score 7):

1. В таймерах функция ссылается не на `setTimeout` (что это вообще значит?), а на `window`.
2. Когда функция вызывается как метод (через точку, например), то `this` внутри устанавливается на родительский объект. А стрелка, соответственно, наследует именно его.
3. Запоминать просто: как функция - `window` (в строгом - `undefined`), как метод - на родительский объект. А потом просто смотреть что и откуда наследует.
   Однако, тут много подводных камней: от `Function#bind` и `Function#apply/call` до стрелок.